# how can control interstitial ads showing in cancel , pause , return

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob, interstitial

I have a game when i clicked return or pause or cancel the ads showing up, and when the player die i want to control the showing ads . The interstitial ads show after each game over.

this is my class which handles Ads:

```
package com.secrethq.ads;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.seth.slex.show.PTPlayer;
import com.seth.slex.show.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

public class PTAdAdMobBridge {
    private static final String TAG = "PTAdAdMobBridge";
    private static Cocos2dxActivity activity;
    private static WeakReference<Cocos2dxActivity> s_activity;
    private static AdView adView;
    private static InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private static LinearLayout layout;
    private static boolean isScheduledForShow;
    private static native void interstitialDidFail();
    private static native void bannerDidFail();

    public static void initBridge(Cocos2dxActivity activity){
        Log.v(TAG, "PTAdAdMobBridge  -- INIT");

        isScheduledForShow = false;

        PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity = new WeakReference<Cocos2dxActivity>(activity); 
        PTAdAdMobBridge.activity = activity;


        PTAdAdMobBridge.initBanner();
        PTAdAdMobBridge.initInterstitial();

    }

    public static void initBanner(){
        Log.v(TAG, "PTAdAdMobBridge  -- initBanner");
        PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView != null){
                    return;
                }

                FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)PTAdAdMobBridge.activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout( PTAdAdMobBridge.activity );
                frameLayout.addView( layout );

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                adViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                adViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                PTAdAdMobBridge.adView = new AdView( PTAdAdMobBridge.activity );
                PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
                PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setAdUnitId(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.admob_id_banner_admob));

                layout.addView(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView, adViewParams);
                PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );

                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.loadAd( adRequest ); 

            }
        });

    }

    public static boolean isBannerVisible(){
        if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView == null){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void initInterstitial(){
        Log.v(TAG, "PTAdAdMobBridge  -- initInterstitial");
        PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if(PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial != null){
                    return;
                }

                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

                PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial = new InterstitialAd( PTAdAdMobBridge.activity );
                String admobid = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.admob_id_interstitial_admob);
                PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.setAdUnitId(admobid);
                if(PTPlayer.setContentView != null)PTPlayer.setContentView.setId(admobid);
                PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        if(PTAdAdMobBridge.isScheduledForShow){
                            PTAdAdMobBridge.showFullScreen();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                        PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitialDidFail();
                    }
                });

                PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

            }
        });
    }



    public static void showFullScreen(){
        Log.v(TAG, "showFullScreen");

        if(PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial != null){
            PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.isLoaded()){
                        if(PTPlayer.is()){
                            if(PTPlayer.wait){
                                PTPlayer.wait = false;
                                PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.show();
                                PTAdAdMobBridge.isScheduledForShow = false;
                            }else{
                                PTPlayer.setContentView();
                                PTPlayer.wait = true;
                            }
                        }else{
                            PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.show();
                            PTAdAdMobBridge.isScheduledForShow = false;
                        }


                    }
                    else{
                        PTAdAdMobBridge.isScheduledForShow = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }



    public static void showBannerAd(){
        Log.v(TAG, "showBannerAd");

        if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView != null){
            PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                    PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.loadAd(adRequest);
                    PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {                 
                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                            PTAdAdMobBridge.bannerDidFail();
                        }
                    });
                    PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                }
            });         
        }



    }

    public static void hideBannerAd(){
        Log.v(TAG, "hideBannerAd");
         if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView != null){
                PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
                    }
                });
         }
    }

}
```

thank you very much

Comment: Is this a Cocos-2dx game? You might be interested in AdMob's C++ interface, which supports Cocos: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/cpp/cocos2d-x

Comment: no is eclipse and i don't know how i can control interstitial ads showing in cancel , pause , return